# Hbs IF statement basics

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I want to do basic thing in hbs, but I'm stacked.
How to write if value greater than 0

{{#if value > 0}} {{/if}}

And if somebody can recommend some good tutorial for Hbs, and isn't PUG simpler to use?

Comment: Read the documentation. No one can read the documentation INSTEAD of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use handlebars [helpers](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helpers) library

Or create own helper:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('greater', function(conditional, value, options) {
 if (conditional > value) {
  return options.fn(this);
 } else {
  return options.inverse(this);
 }
});
```

and use it:

```
{{#greater value 0}} {{/greater}}
```